# How to convert ISO 8601 string PT1H4M13S in php

Tags: php, string

I want to convert this ISO 8601 string `PT1H4M13S` into `1:04:13`

you can see in string H M and S its hour minute and second

i want a function which play with this string and give me 1:04:13

here is my code

```
function convertiso($iso){
    //PT4M13S
    $rem_pt = str_replace('PT', '', $iso); //Remove PT from string
    return $rem_pt;
}

echo convertiso('PT1H4M13S'); // output 1H4M13S
```

firstly i have remove PT secondly i don't know how to get done this need help.

Comment: Please attempt to code a solution and ask a concrete question when you encounter problems.

Comment: @JonSurrell sir i have update what i am trying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for this.

Construct the [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object, then [format it](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) the way you need.

```
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1H4M13S');
echo $interval->format("%H:%I:%S");
```

https://eval.in/409488